# Sql problems with combinations of multiple characteristics to result in a number to index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Lets say i have a simple table:

**Laptops**

```
Id (int autoincrement, 
Name nvarchar(50)  
2gb Ram ( bit ),
4gb Ram ( bit ),
250 hdd ( bit )
500 hdd ( bit )
```

So we have a table for laptops and it has just 4 possible configurations.

If it has 2gb ram and a 250gb hdd, then it has

```
 (id product), (name product) 1 0 1 0
```

I hope this is simple.

Now i want to get these 4 characteristics which can have muliple combinations and represent them in a number.

So then when a user selects that he wants a laptop with 2gb ram and 250gb,
I will then have a column in database called 'Characteristics_combinatons'

So that 1 0 1 0 becomes .. something like .. 1010.

So i will do

```
Select * from Laptops where Characteristics_combinatons = 1010.
```

Then i can have an index on that column and the user will search for the products must faster.

Is there a much better way or standard way to deal with such things ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat()` to create a column and then search for that.  I would use a string:

```
alter table laptops add combo as (concat([2gb Ram], [4gb Ram], [250 hdd], [500 hdd]) persisted;

create index idx_laptops_combo on laptops(combo);

select l.*
from laptops
where combo = '1010';
```

Comment: That works, but what if i have many many characteristics like couple of 100s.Should i just create a integer hash type?

Comment: This is what happens when you VASTLY over-simplify your actual situation. And this smells of premature optimization, but no one can really say without knowing what you are actually modelling and how you intend to use it. Your column names highly suggest improper normalization. You should have a column for the amount of memory - not multiple "flags". If I had to guess, you are designing your database to fit how you think you will design your GUI.

Comment: @Aflred . . . This answers the question that you have asked -- and this can be extended to many, many columns if you like.  You should ask *new* questions as a *new question*, not in a comment.  Be sure that is more closely aligned with what you really want to do.